# How to check what button is clicked in another activity?

Tags: android, function, button

The program I been doing has a language button which after clicking the button, it will direct to other activity and 3 language button will be shown and after clicking one of the button, the button should send a code back to the main activity and after that use a switch to determine the code and play the audio respectively. Here are my codes, please have a look:

**Main Activity:**

```
Button languages = findViewById(R.id.languages);
languages.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent (CameraActivity.this, LanguageSelection.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent,1);
  }
});
```

**Language Selection Code:**

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_selection);

    Button english = findViewById(R.id.english);
    Button malay = findViewById(R.id.malay);
    Button chinese = findViewById(R.id.chinese);

    english.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent (LanguageSelection.this, CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("langCode", 0);
            setResult(0,intent);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    malay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent (LanguageSelection.this, CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("langCode", 1);
            setResult(1,intent);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    chinese.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            Intent intent = new Intent (LanguageSelection.this, CameraActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("langCode", 2);
            setResult(2,intent);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}
```

**Switch in Main Activity**

```
@UiThread
protected void showResultsInBottomSheet(List<Recognition> results) {
 if (results != null && results.size() >= 3) {
  Recognition recognition = results.get(0);
  if (recognition != null) {
    if (recognition.getTitle() != null) recognitionTextView.setText(recognition.getTitle());
    if (recognition.getConfidence() != null)
      recognitionValueTextView.setText(
              String.format("%.2f", (100 * recognition.getConfidence())) + "%");
    float confi = 100 * recognition.getConfidence();
    try {
      switch (language) {

          case 0:
            if (!rm1 && recognitionTextView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("RM1") && confi > 80) {
              mp0.start();
              rm1 = true;
              rm5 = false;
              rm10 = false;
              rm20 = false;
              rm50 = false;
              rm100 = false;
            }
          case 1:
            if (!rm1 && recognitionTextView.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("RM1") && confi > 80) {
              mp6.start();
              rm1 = true;
              rm5 = false;
              rm10 = false;
              rm20 = false;
              rm50 = false;
              rm100 = false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following:

1. Call the language activity as:  `startActivityForResult(intent, 0);`
2. In language activity instead of calling `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);` you should call  `setResult(0,intent);`
3. In main activity you should add a method to handle the results:

```
    int language;
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(requestCode==0)
        {
             language=data.getIntExtra("langCode");
        }
    }
```

And then you can use variable `language` to get the selected language across tha MainActivity.

Also there is no need for line     `int language = intent.getIntExtra("langCode",0);` since you dont do nothing with it in Language activity.

Comment: so for the switch, I should write switch(onActivityResult().message) in the statement?

Comment: i've edited my answer and included the switch.

Comment: I see your edit, if i understand it correctly you call showResultsInBottomSheet from somewhere else in MainActivity and you just want to save the language from Language activity to use here, right?

Comment: Okay i've edited my answer again. Then you just have to use the variable language for the switch

Comment: Sorry to say, I don't know why but seems like the value of language can't send to the switch. As you can see in my new edit, I plan on using the value of language to decide what audio to be play. In this case mp0 is english and mp6 is malay. But no matter how I try the app only speaks in english unless I set the code as int language == 1; then only it will change to malay.

Comment: Thats strange. I see you're also opening CameraActivity after setting the result. How do you then get back to MainActivity? Also have you try putting a breakpoint at onActivityResult?

Comment: the CameraActivity is my MainActivity.

Comment: oooh okay. instead of calling  startActivity to go back from language activity you should just call finish()

Comment: And for the intent with which you return language just use Intent intent = new Intent() since you dont want to navigate anywhere, just finish the language activity